# How to get address from using tokenId

Tags: solidity

I'm looking for a way to get the token minter address by using the tokenId. I know I can access the token owner by using `ownerOf(tokenId)`, but that returns the current address where the token is being held. I want to perform a require statement that looks something like this `require(minterOf(tokenId) == msg.sender`. Is there a way to reference this value in Solidity?

For context I am creating a web application that allows users to supply any data they choose to mint ERC721 tokens. I want give the minter a feature that allows them to burn the token even if it exists in an address they do not control.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that natively in solidity since you cannot communicate with the blockchain, only send data to it. You'd have to use an explorer for that, to track transactions.
You cannot track transactions through solidity, only the current transaction (with tx.origin or tx.gasprice members).

You could probably create an extension that does that and records owners through transfers by overriding the `safeTransferFrom` - `transferFrom` - `transfer` ... and having it store what you need in struct or arrays. To my knowledge that doesn't exist yet.

Your best shot is to use APIs to track the transfer of said NFT with the id through events.
You can easily do that with etherscan manually.
Maybe etherscan API or alchemy could have those features.
Building it yourself would be a very very difficut task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wonder if there is an oracle that already does this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to complete this natively in Solidity. I created a mapping for the minter address:

`mapping(uint256 => address) private _minters;`

I overrode the _mint function from ERC721.sol like this:

```
   function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override {
       super._mint(to, tokenId);
       _minters[tokenId] = msg.sender;
   }
```

And created a revoke function that only allows the minter to burn tokens that were minted by themselves but are being held by other wallets.

```
 function revokeCredential(uint256 tokenId) external {
    require(
        _minters[tokenId] == msg.sender,
        "Only the issuer can revoke a credential"
    );
    _burn(tokenId);
}
```